# How to remove title from RichTextEditor control in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

It is possible to remove some `RichTextEditor` control bar with `showControlBar` property.

But how to remove title bar too?

The following code displays control WITH empty title bar:

```
<mx:RichTextEditor id="mLog" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="41"
    dropShadowVisible="false" showControlBar="false">
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the title bar remained when I was testing my answer to your last question. I'll see if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this look?

```
<mx:RichTextEditor showControlBar="false" dropShadowEnabled="false" 
                           headerHeight="0" 
                           borderThicknessLeft="0" borderThicknessRight="0"
                           borderThicknessTop="0" borderThicknessBottom="0"/>
```

`headerHeight` sets the title bar height to 0. The 4 `borderThicknessXXX` settings remove the borders that still showed.